# python 2.7 function to use for python 3.8 hex/encoding issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sockets, hex

I have the following hex function which works great in conjunction with python 2.7

```
#Python 2.7 code
 def dehex(d):
        return "".join(map(chr, d))

test = dehex([0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x71,0x7f,0xd8,0xfe,0x03,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x00])
sock.sendto(test, (addr, port))
response = sock.recv(4096)
```

However in python 3.8 it doesn't allow me to send a "string" so it wants me to use encode() however this messes with the test dehex output and results in wrongly formatted bytes like the following:

```
#Python 3.8 fail code
 def dehex(d):
        return "".join(map(chr, d))

test = dehex([0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x71,0x7f,0xd8,0xfe,0x03,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x00])
sock.sendto(test.encode(), (addr, port))
response = sock.recv(4096)
```

How can i essentially use the dehex function on python 3.8, so i don't have to use encode('utf-8')?

Comment: What is the function meant to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bytearray` should be 2.7 and 3.8 compatible:

```
def dehex(d):
    return bytes(bytearray(d))
```